# now i'm confused . .. does Adobe Flash support iOS or not?

Tags: ios, flash

i see tons of articles on why apple doesn't support flash in iOS and why flash won't work on ipads and ipods.  I see lots of flash sites not work properly when i launch them with mhy ipad but now i see articles about [flash supporting iOS](http://www.arnnet.com.au/article/391041/ios_blackberry_tablet_os_supported_latest_adobe_update/?fp=4&fpid=56736) so are all of those other articles wrong.  Can i now write an application and flash and have it work on the web in ipad and iphones ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash is not supported in the browser, however, you can package up a Flash application and install it on your iOS device. This should clear things up:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs-55-web-premium-feature-tour-/flash-professional-cs55-publishing-content-to-ios-devices/

Answer (score 4):

No.  iOS does not support flash.  What's more likely is that Adobe has released a crosscompiler that translates a flash binary into a native iOS application.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm reading it, it means you can develop applications in flash and export them for iOS, not that flash is coming to iOS.